# Jquery mouseover and mouseout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was making a custom play pause button to my video . However when I mouse over the button the button will keep blinking . Any idea stop the blinking when I mouse over the button ? Thanks

```js
$('#fullplay')
    .mouseover(function () {
        $('#playpausevideo').fadeIn();
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        $('#playpausevideo').fadeOut();
    });
```

```css
.container{
  
  }

.playpausevideo{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('/../../Images/onbigplan/bigfullplay.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:99999;
}
.playpausevideo.selected{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('/../../Images/onbigplan/bigfullpause.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="playpausevideo" class="playpausevideo noselected"></div>
<video id="fullplay" autoplay muted loop poster="" width="400px" height:="300px">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your video and button into a div, and listen `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on that div.

Here's a jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/jp5ru8vz/